# Disable isotope filter preloading?

Tags: jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I am using http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ - to filter a portfolio on my website. Because it is getting a bit heavy on the loading (plenty of images) I want to disable the pre-loading of all the filters (categories) and make them load only when each category is clicked. 
Any ideas on how to do that?

Example: Right now all the images for all the categories are preloaded, so when you navigate from one category to the other there is no wait, I want to change that as per my description above.

Comment: You need to post the code that you have so far. Your "description" is not enough info. Please clarify your question about preloading a filter. Do you mean preloading only specific filtered images first? How will people know what other images to filter if they are not loaded?

Comment: It's the default isotope js code and functionality. The website is here: (http://www.lonewulf.eu) - now the images from all the categories are all loaded but I was wondering if it's possible to load them only when the category they belong is clicked. I guess you are right though and it's not "possible" since they need to be filtered.

Comment: Not sure how you can access images not yet loaded to filter with isotope. I think your loading issues are partially related to ````$("#pfinner").load("portfolio.html");````. All your relevant code is in portfolio.html, not your index page, which most likely adds a significant delay. Are you using isotope v2 ( it looks like 1.56) and imagesloaded?

Comment: I'll try to move the portfolio code over to index to see if it helps, but I just used this method to make the index cleaner. Yes I don't think I am using v2 because my portfolio wasn't working when I tried it, also I am not using imagesLoaded.

Comment: I moved everything on the index and it seems to load/behave better so thanks!